# Access xterm's scrollback buffer as a file

Tags: xterm

Is it possible to, somehow, access xterm's scrollback buffer as a (read-only) file or a character device?

The core issue (to avoid x/y "problemming"), is this:
sometimes the command I've just executed creates non-deterministic output, and I'd like to use its output somehow without pre-thought of tee-ing it. Right now, the only way to do this (that I'm aware of) is to use the mouse to select the text into primary selection.

Comment: Alternative to using `tee`. Have you considered running `script` to create a log of all your commands to a file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do this by telling xterm to print the data using the [**`print-everything`**](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#Actions:print-everything) action (normally not bound to a key).

Alternatively, there's an escape sequence documented in [XTerm Control Sequences](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-?-Pm-i.1D0F):

```
CSI ? Pm i                                                                      
          Media Copy (MC), DEC-specific.                                        
            Ps = 1  -> Print line containing cursor.                            
            Ps = 4  -> Turn off autoprint mode.                                 
            Ps = 5  -> Turn on autoprint mode.                                  
            Ps = 1  0  -> Print composed display, ignores DECPEX.               
            Ps = 1  1  -> Print all pages.
```

which could be invoked as

```
printf '\033[?11i'
```

But either approach (to write to a file) would need a [printerCommand](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:printerCommand) configured.

Comment: Is it possible to do that without restarting xterm? If it involves restarting xterm it is not really an answer as that would cause the output to be lost.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Resources can be reloaded on the fly, and I'm OK to restart xterm.
I've created a named fifo and configured it into printerCommand, have bound print-everything command to a key and it works exactly as I wanted it to.

Comment: This may have security implications because any program with the user rights or root rights can trigger `printf '\033[?11i' > /dev/pts/[number]` and then examine the output.

Comment: However, if this is to be configured permanently, just add this line to ~/.Xresources: `xterm*VT100.printerCommand: cat >~/XTerm.pseudoprinter.out` and make sure this is loaded by `xrdb -load` on startup (will probably happen automatically on your GNU/Linux system).

Answer (score 2):

You can always use something like tmux which provides `capture-pane` that does what you want, along with splits (vertical and horizontal) and multiplexing, session support, and a slew of other things.

Or use a different terminal emulator `xfce4-terminal` is also lightweight and provides an easy `Save Contents`

Comment: To me this does not sound like an answer to the question. None of those programs can magically capture output which at the moment exist only in an xterm window.

Comment: @kasperd a fair interpretation. He wants something that captures without pre-thought. I use `tmux` without prethought. Then I don't have this problem. If you can get in the habit of using tmux, you'll never have to think about this again (or a lot of other stuff).

Answer (score 0):

You can Ctrl-Clickleft and select "Print-All Immediately" which generates the plain text file `$HOME/XTermYYYY-MM-DD.hh.mm.ss`

This is the default configuration which can be modified with `printFileImmediate`, `printModeImmediate` and `printOptsImmediate`.